# How to make Latex recognize individual keywords in lstlisting without delimiter?

Tags: listings, delimiters, keywords

I want to add a few lines of G-Code (used for 3D-printing) to my latex file using the listing package. Unfortunately, g-code is not supported as a language and therefore has no highlighted commands. I tried adding the command keywords manually, as you can see below, but it didn't quiet work out the way I intended.

```
\documentclass[
    12pt
    ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\lstset{
 morekeywords={E, T, G1, F, X, Y}
}
\begin{lstlisting}
T0
G1 E2 F80 
G1 Z0.400 F7800.00
G1 F300.000 E-1.00000

G1 X88.172 Y88.172 F7800.000
G1 E1.00000 F300.000 
G1 X111.828 Y88.172 E0.01225 F360.000
G1 X111.828 Y111.828 E0.01225
\end{lstlisting}    

\end{document}
```

results in:

[image]

How can I make latex recognize keywords, even if they are not followed by a delimiter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keywords goes until the first "non-digit or non-letter". So you need to make the number to other:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt
    ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}


\begin{document}

\lstset{
 morekeywords={E, T, G1, F, X, Y},
 alsoother={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
}
\begin{lstlisting}
T0
G1 E2 F80
G1 Z0.400 F7800.00
G1 F300.000 E-1.00000

G1 X88.172 Y88.172 F7800.000
G1 E1.00000 F300.000
G1 X111.828 Y88.172 E0.01225 F360.000
G1 X111.828 Y111.828 E0.01225
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But with this setting the G1 keyword no longer work.

If you really want every occurance of the single letter to be bold you could try this:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt
    ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
    \lst@ProcessOther {"45}{%
      \lst@ttfamily
         {\textbf{E}}% used with ttfamily
         {\textbf{E}}}% used with other fonts
    \lst@ProcessOther {"54}{%
      \lst@ttfamily
         {\textbf{T}}% used with ttfamily
         {\textbf{T}}}% used with other fonts  
    \lst@ProcessOther {"46}{%
      \lst@ttfamily
         {\textbf{F}}% used with ttfamily
         {\textbf{F}}}% used with other fonts                
    \lst@ProcessOther {"58}{%
      \lst@ttfamily
         {\textbf{X}}% used with ttfamily
         {\textbf{X}}}% used with other fonts         
    \lst@ProcessOther {"59}{%
      \lst@ttfamily
         {\textbf{Y}}% used with ttfamily
         {\textbf{Y}}}% used with other fonts         
    \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother  
\begin{document}

\lstset{
 morekeywords={G1},
 }
\begin{lstlisting}
T0
G1 E2 F80
G1 Z0.400 F7800.00
G1 F300.000 E-1.00000

G1 X88.172 Y88.172 F7800.000
G1 E1.00000 F300.000
G1 X111.828 Y88.172 E0.01225 F360.000
G1 X111.828 Y111.828 E0.01225
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Quite alot of code, but it works. Could you give me some background on the "\lst@ProcessOther{}" function and the arguments like "45 and so on?  Couldn't find it in the listings documentation...

Comment: The numbers are the positions of the chars (in hexadecimal), the function is the function listings uses internally when processing a char. You won't find it in the documentation, I found it by looking in the code.